# Date converted wrongly

Tags: php, date, datetime

When i run the following code

```
echo date('l jS \of F Y', strtotime('22/08/2018'));
```

the output is

> Thursday 1st of January 1970

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

It is to do with the difference between US an European date formats.

With slashes `strtotime` reads MM/DD/YY with hyphens it reads DD-MM-YY

Replacing the slashes with dashes will tell it to use the correct format.

```
echo date('l jS \of F Y', strtotime('22-08-2018'));
```

Will print `Wednesday 22nd of August 2018`

> ...Forward slash (/) signifies American M/D/Y formatting, a
>   dash (-) signifies European D-M-Y and a period (.) signifies ISO
>   Y.M.D.

From the most up voted User Contributed Notes on: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that output is because strtotime can't parse the date.
If you look in the manual it has a list of what date formats that can be parsed.

If you must use that date format you can use date_create_from_format to parse it.

```
$datetime = date_create_from_format ( "d/m/Y" , $dateString);
```

This returns a DateTime object that you can manipulate as you wish.
Example:

```
$dateString = '22/08/2018';
$datetime = date_create_from_format ( "d/m/Y" , $dateString);

echo date_format ( $datetime , 'l jS \of F Y' );
```

Will output:

```
Wednesday 22nd of August 2018
```

https://3v4l.org/WLgNK